# Link to app manage subscriptions in app store

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit, openurl

Currently with In app purchase the only way to cancel an auto-renewing subscription is to do the following with the device:

Settings > Store > View my account > Manage my subscription

Is it possible programmatically to link directly to the Manage my subscription page in the app store?  I know I can open the app store via something like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I have seen other apps do this but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 118):

### Using a URL

According to Apples article [Handling Subscriptions Billing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing) and [WWDC 2018 Session 705](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/) the following url can be used to link to the manage subscription page:

`https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions`

### Using StoreKit/SwiftUI (iOS 15+)

**UIKit:** Use StoreKits `showManageSubscriptions(in:)` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions)).

**SwiftUI**: Use SwiftUIs modifier `manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented:)` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/managesubscriptionssheet(ispresented:))).

Comment: This should now be the preferred answer. Works, thank you!

Comment: This seems to be the "official way", but in when I open the URL via `openURL()`, on iOS 12, first Safari opens, forwards to another site `finance-app.itunes.apple.com`, where a popup shows up "Open this page in iTunes Store?". If you tap "Open", the "iTunes Store" app opens, and the desired screen appears as a modal overlay. Ugh. Is there a smoother way, without redirects, preferably so that either the Settings app or the App Store app opens? (That's what I would expect as a user.)

Comment: @Theo see answer from mklb: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53275848/686902

Comment: The new one https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions redirects to App Store, and *only works on iOS 12 or later*. 
The old one https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions redirects to iTunes Store. Both are [official](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/?time=1501) [ways](https://web.archive.org/web/20190606015547/https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW19). Tested on my iOS 10-13 devices.

Comment: Would like to point out that this doesn't take you to the App Store application, it opens up iTunes. This link, https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions, used to work and would take you to the App Store, not iTunes. But that link no longer works.

Comment: This links to iTunes. The title of this question clearly states it would like to take the user to the App Store. Using this link itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions will open the App Store app on your phone or computer if you are on a Mac.

Comment: Can i linked to specific package in this page?

Comment: Its not redirecting to manage subscription for tvOS? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As of iOS 15 this should be the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71836610/4884617

Comment: How can I only show/direct user to my app in the the https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions
?

Answer (score 37):

Following this [iTunes Connect guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-DontLinkElementID_1ml), this URL works:

```
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
```

> You can link directly to the Manage Subscriptions page in the App
>   Store without having to write your own manage subscriptions page. To
>   do so, link to this URL:
>   https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions

However this will redirect to Safari before redirecting to App Store App. So the user will see app switching twice in their device. Changing `https` to `itms` or `itms-apps` does not seem to just work.

Btw, this only works on the device. It wouldn't work on the simulator.

Comment: This link also takes the user to iTunes and not the App Store as the question title states.

Comment: This link was working on a device but recently it stops working on the device. It returns this:


pings metrics dialogIdMZFinance.ManageSubscriptionsLoginRequired messageSign in to manage subscri messageCode5074 options Manage Subscriptions Cancel actionUrlbuy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions eventTypedialog failureType5074 customerMessageSign in to manage subscriptions. m-allowed dialog kindauthorization m-allowed messageSign in to manage subscriptions. explanationEnter your Apple ID and password and click Manage Subscriptions. defaultButtonok okButtonS...

Answer (score 33):

2018 on IOS its a combination of the answers above. This URL will open the App Store App with the correct view:

`itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions`

Comment: As of Nov 2018, this is the best approach.

Comment: This should be the top voted answer. It is the the only one that takes you to the App Store. All the other solutions either no longer work or take you to iTunes.  This will work as a browser link as well.

Answer (score 33):

As of Nov 2018, this is the best approach.

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to direct the users to the AppStore -> Subscriptions. The previous pref "itms://" was redirecting to iTunes Store -> Subscriptions.

Answer (score 19):

The above answers are possibly slightly out of date (including Apple's documentation grrr) as I am receiving a Safari error when trying to use the link:

```
// old way
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
```

Using XCode 5.1 and iOS 7.x, I am able to correctly link to the "Manage Subscriptions" section for the app in question using the following `openURL:` call:

```
// new way
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"]]
```

Comment: This links to iTunes. The title of this question clearly states it would like to take the user to the App Store.

Answer (score 10):

use this link to skip past safari and right to the screen in the appstore:

```
itmss://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
```

have fun

Comment: where did you find this "itmss:" from? Just trial and error or is there an actual documentation for this?

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I tried this today, it took me to the iTunes Store (not App Store), asked me for my password and worked. But When I went back to the app and execute it again, it's just giving me iTunes Store's home screen. I'll stick with https for now until Apple fix this.

Comment: This links to iTunes. The title of this question clearly states it would like to take the user to the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS15+, the [showManageSubscriptions(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions) function presents the App Store sheet for managing subscriptions.

[image]

Comment: And  manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented:) for SwiftUI

Comment: Is it possible to call this from Objective C?

Comment: Unfortunately, this API can only be called in Swift.
This is because this functionality was introduced in StoreKit 2, which is a "modern Swift-based APIs".

Comment: StoreKit2 : https://developer.apple.com/storekit/

WWDC Video : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10887/?time=261

Comment: This method is broken for me. After the sheet is dismissed I lose all UI input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my small Swift 5 contribution:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
```

I hope it helps someone =)

Thanks to this answer: [Opening Apple's subscription window from within app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328288/opening-apples-subscription-window-from-within-app/65328527#65328527)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the new URL used by Apple in its support pages is `https://finance-app.itunes.apple.com/account/subscriptions`. This will open the iTunes Store app on any iOS device.

Answer (score -1):

My app has recently been rejected for providing an external subscription management option in my app. The message I got from Apple Dev Team was: "We still found that while you have submitted In App Purchase products for your app, the In App Purchase functionality is not present in your binary. Specifically, the 'Manage Subscriptions' option links out of the app to iTunes Store."

I provided an view so the user can "Restore/Subscribe" to a yearly auto-renewable subscription (of course I have added the underlying logic to detect when the user is subscribed / not subscribed, and a "Manage my subscriptions" button that allows the user to manage his subscription via itunes (which is something I got out from various sources including this post).

I think this should be avoided in order to have the IAP product accepted. Perhaps  you faced the same issue when submitting the app to review.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.