# Link to manage Play Store subscription

Tags: android, google-play

On iOS, we can use https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions, and it will open the native subscription manager.

Is this possible to do this with the Play Store, or is there any other possible way to open the native subscription manager for Google Play Store?

Same as this question, but for Android: [Link to app manage subscriptions in app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530794/link-to-app-manage-subscriptions-in-app-store).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I use Action view to open Google Play Store -> Account.

```
    private fun openPlaystoreAccount() {
        try {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account?utm_source=google&utm_medium=account&utm_campaign=my-account")));
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            showToast("Cant open the browser")
            e.printStackTrace()
        } 
    }
```

**Update:**

Google released a new deep link, where it will take users directly to your app manage subscription page. You need two things SKU and your app package name.

Example URL:

https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=yoursku&package=com.yourpackagename

Sample Code in Kotlin:

```
 private val packageName = "com.mydomain.myapp"
 private val sku = "mySku"

 private fun openPlaystoreAccount() {
     try {
         startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=$sku&package=$packageName")))
     } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
         showToast("Cant open the browser")
         e.printStackTrace()
     }
 }
```

Comment: How would you direct a user if there are numerous SKUs for different subscriptions options? Is there a more general link?

Comment: Is there a way to know whether the user successfully unsubscribed from said this deep link intent? Any return of result from the actions done by user from the deeplink?

Comment: For some reason this specific deep link doesn't seem to work anymore in more recent Play Store versions.

Comment: Google's Doc for this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#deep-link

Answer (score 19):

I could not find out how to link to the subscriptions page for a specific app. But the url to go to the subscriptions page is: https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions. This url will open in the Play Store app when you're on Android.

Comment: For convenience when testing, one can launch this URL via the command-line with this adb command: `adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions`

Answer (score 4):

A user can view their subscriptions on the App store page now.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#deep-link

> "After users have purchased subscriptions, they can view the subscriptions and cancel them from the My Apps screen in the Play Store app or from the app's product details page in the Play Store app."

`market://details?id=YOUR_APP_ID`

Answer (score 4):

Since this year's IO it is possible to use a **deep link** to link to your subscriptions:

```
https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=*yoursku*&package=*com.yourpackagename*
```

Simply open this URL with a regular intent.

Answer (score 4):

A more detailed explanation -

**1) User already owns a subscription**

In this case when you call `billingClient.queryPurchases()`, which returns a `PurchaseResult`. This has details such as the `purchaseToken` and the `sku` as well as the `packagename`. This call is made every time the app starts or a `MainActivity` is Resumed, because if someone buys your IAP offline you also need to `acknowledge` a purchase (more on this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#acknowledgepurchase))

This means you can also let the user "Manage" subscription, so the deeplink to link to is:

`https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?sku=skuName&package=packageName`

**2) User is about to buy a subscription:**

The way to do this is capture `productId` or `Sku` of the SUBS IAP you created in the Play console. Then you build the `flowParams`, and then you can call

```
val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
            .build()

billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams)
```

If successful, this means you get back two things: `BillingResult` and `MutableList<Purchase>`. If the `BillingResult` is `OK`, and the list returned is not empty, the purchase was succesful. This object also has the `sku` and `packageName`, so you follow the same deeplink as above for the user to `Manage` their subscription.

**3) The user has canceled their subscription, and their subscription has expired but is within any of the `Resubscribe` period conditions stated [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#deep-link)**

This is when you show this deeplink:

`https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions`, so they can restore or resubscribe the same `Sku` they had before.

p.s. One thing to note is the `Play Store` app supports multiple users. So the deeplink will only work if the `Play Store` app has the correct user selected.

[image: Tap on the letter avatar on the top right to change accounts]

Answer (score 1):

#### So this is what I did to link directly to a subscription:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val packageName =  context.applicationContext.packageName
val subscription_id = "Your subcription ID"
val PLAY_STORE_SUBSCRIPTION_DEEPLINK_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions?product=%s&package=%s"
val url = String.format(PLAY_STORE_SUBSCRIPTION_DEEPLINK_URL,
        subscription_id, packageName);
```

- You can find your `subscription_id` in the google play console under Monetization -> Subscriptions

##### Jetpack compose code:

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(url:String) {
    val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current
    Button(onClick = { uriHandler.openUri(url) }){
        Text("Subscriptions")
    }
}
```