# Navigating to payments and subscriptions settings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-navigation, android-settings

I would like to navigate to payments and subscriptions settings when the user clicks a button. So far I tried solutions like that but similar solutions mostly navigate users to the Play Store.

```
                    val uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account")
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                    intent.addFlags(
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT or
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
                    )
                    activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Is it possible to go to the payments and subscriptions settings programmatically?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229715/15388934

The question is very similar to yours.