# Is it possible to open Android / iOS subscriptions manager from a Xamarin app?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, subscription

I desire to create a button labeled as "Manage your subscription", which will perform an action of opening the subscriptions manager of the runtime platform(ios or android). This would avoid to code  requisitions to Google Play's and App Store's API.

For example, this will open the manager for some settings of the runtime platform:

`Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI();`

How can I achieve something like that for subscriptions?

Comment: Related: [Link to manage Play Store subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082403/295004)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by deep linking to these urls:

For android play store => https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions

For ios app store => https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions

Comment: Thanks, @Éder Rocha. Could give a hint about how to use deep linking for this? I created a URL scheme and an OpenUrl override in AppDelegate, but when I access the url, the OpenUrl override is not reached. I am using WebView.