# App Store subscriptions url works in iPhone Safari but in Xamarin Forms fails to connect to iTunes store

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview, revenuecat

I am using a url that, in iPhone Safari, takes me to a list of my App Store subscriptions. However when I use Xamarin Forms WebView to display that same url in my iOS solution, it wrongly displays another page entirely. The url is:
https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions

My code is simply:

```
webView = new WebView
{
    Margin = new Thickness ( 0D ),
    Source = "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions",
    WidthRequest = Bounds.Width,
    HeightRequest = Bounds.Height
};
stackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Margin = new Thickness ( 0D ),
    Padding = new Thickness ( 0D ),
    WidthRequest = Bounds.Width,
    HeightRequest = Bounds.Height,
    Children = { webView }
};
Content = stackLayout;
```

Is it possible to get around this problem (for example in native iOS code), or is it simply a matter of Safari having integrations that the underlying native WkWebView does not?

Note: In iPhone Safari, the content is essentially the same as when I go to iPhone Settings > Profile picture > Subscriptions. However in WebView, I get an iTunes page saying "Connecting to the iTunes Store" (it never does), followed by "If you don't have iTunes, download it for free. If you have iTunes and it doesn't open automatically, try opening it from your dock or Windows taskbar".

Fwiw the url was supplied by the RevenueCat API.

Comment: *"it wrongly displays another page entirely."* IMHO, That's not a good description of what happens. As you say later in question, what actually happens is you get an itunes page "Connecting to the iTunes Store". etc. I would move that description up to the first paragraph, instead of the misleading phrase I quoted. REASON: This makes it clearer early in question that it isn't some weird glitch, its Apple trying to retrieve some information from iTunes. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the details, so I can't help solve the problem. Just making it easier for others to understand. Edited title.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ToolmakerSteve. I'd stand by the description though, because what you get should be the same as what you get in iPhone Safari.

Comment: The following also don't work: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions and itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions

Comment: Also https://finance-app.itunes.apple.com/account/subscriptions does not work.

Comment: In a post, @Éder Rocha reports success using deep linking. However I have not been able to make that work - not familiar with deep linking.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622063/is-it-possible-to-open-android-ios-subscriptions-manager-from-a-xamarin-app