# Opening Apple's subscription window from within app

Tags: swift, in-app-subscription

Is there a way to open the iPhone's Subscriptions Management window by clicking on a button within the app?

I know you can open the app's settings page with

```
UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
```

Is there something similar to access the Subscriptions module in order to manage in-app subscriptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open subscription settings, use this URL:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions")
UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:])
```